Cannot access public google docs using the google doc API and its url
I am able to successfully access google docs within my own google drive. The problem is that when I publish the document and try to access it through the published domain, I get the error:
HttpError 404 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/2PACX-1vSHesOf9hv2sPOntssYrEdubmMQm8lwjfwv6NPjjmIRYs_FOYXtqrYgjh85jBUebK9swPXh_a5TJ5Kl?alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found."

I have tried every configuration of permissions on my service account and every different configuration of the documentID, but it always says entity was not found.
I am expecting to get the json from the document webpage and then parse through the data.
